# Cleaning up JSON Extract in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, string

This json_extract works but it's messy and I want to clean it up but I can't figure out how.

```
json_unquote(json_extract(
    json_unquote(json_extract(
        json_unquote(json_extract(
            json_unquote(json_extract(
                json_unquote(json_extract(
                    json_unquote(json_extract(response, '$.output')), '$.output')), '$.risk_score_model_result')), '$.value')), '$.ModelInputs')), '$.fieldname')) as fieldname;
```

I tried using `->` and `->>` but I can only get it to work one layer deep. For example, `response -> '$.output'` works, but
`response ->> '$.output' ->> '$.output'` or any variation of `->` and `->>` throws a syntax error.

I'm a novice (clearly) when it comes to MySQL and json extracts, so thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are overcomplicating things here. Both `json_extract()`, `->` and `->>`  take a JSON *path* as argument. So this:

```
response ->> '$.output' ->> '$.output'
```

Should be written:

```
response ->> '$.output.output'
```

If we apply the same logic to your big nested expression, I think that should become:

```
response ->> '$.output.output.risk_score_model_result.value.ModelInputs.fieldname'
```